# Change the appearance of a Spinner in Android

Tags: android, styles, spinner

I want to change the appearance of a spinner so that it looks like a textview at the outside. My current approach is this:

```
 <Spinner 
     android:id="@+id/spinner"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     style="@style/spinner_style"/>
```

and the style resources:

```
 <style name="spinner_style" parent ="@android:attr/textViewStyle">
     <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/MyText</item>

 </style>


<style name="MyText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#00ffff</item>
</style>
```

It does not throw any error but also has no effect on the appearance. Alternativly I might bind a spinner on a Textview, but don't know how :)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to change the background of the spinner as that's what gives it the 'spinner' look (textarea + arrow).

```
<item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

It would be best to use a 9-Patch drawing to replace the background so you can represent any text properly.

Comment: i tried to set <item name="android:background">@color/red</item> and it worked great. Best would be to set it to null to have no background. How would I do this in XML ?

Comment: I'm confused. If you tried setting the background to red and it worked, why wouldn't you just keep it that way? Your comment *is* using XML, you are just using the styles to achieve what you need, which is a good thing.

Comment: I don't want the background to be red, I want it to be invisible like a normal textview. <item name="android:background">@color/null</item> is not working since null is unknown ...

Comment: Oh I see what you want. You need to use the *transparent* color. See edited solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set background to null:

```
<item name="android:background">@null</item>
```